# Resizing a WebGL VertexBuffer to dynamically add instanced objects?

Tags: javascript

I'm have my WebGL2 app set up like this (using PicoGL to abstract a bit over the WebGL calls):

```
...

let positions = app.createVertexBuffer(PicoGL.FLOAT, 3, box.positions);
let uv = app.createVertexBuffer(PicoGL.FLOAT, 2, box.uvs);
const sides = app.createVertexBuffer(PicoGL.INT, 1, new Int32Array([
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // front:  0,  0,  1
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, // right:  1,  0,  0
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, //  back:  0,  0, -1
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, //  left: -1,  0,  0
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, //   top:  0,  1,  0
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, //  bttm:  0, -1,  0
]));

let boxArray = app.createVertexArray()
        .vertexAttributeBuffer(0, positions)
        .vertexAttributeBuffer(1, uv)
        .vertexAttributeBuffer(2, sides)
        .instanceAttributeBuffer(3, offsetsAttr)
        .instanceAttributeBuffer(4, texturesAttr);

const drawCall = app.createDrawCall(program, boxArray);

...

const draw = () => {
    app.clear();
    drawCall.draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
};

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

Now, I want to add more boxes -- so I need to update `offsetsAttr` and `texturesAttr` to have longer arrays. But when I try to update the attributes, the number of objects on the screen stays constant -- when the new one appears, one of the old ones disappears.

I tried 2 things:

- Updating the vertex buffer with `gl.bufferData(..., gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW)` (NOT `bufferSubData`, because that would obviously not be able to expand the array)
- Recreating the VertexBuffer entirely and rebinding it to the location on `boxArray`

Both have the same behavior, so I'm stumped. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a WebGL question. It seems like a pico.gl question. It would seem you need to tell picogl that you increased the buffer size and therefore it needs to call `gl.drawArrays` with a higher count. There's no way it can divine that. maybe `drawCall.numInstances = newNumInstances`

Comment: Thanks! I needed to set drawCall.numInstances -- totally slipped my mind to do that. If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

PicoGL currently sets the draw counts when a [DrawCall is constructed](https://github.com/tsherif/picogl.js/blob/master/src/draw-call.js#L73-L75) if a `VertexArray` is provided. You can set draw counts explicitly using the [DrawCall.drawRanges](https://tsherif.github.io/picogl.js/docs/DrawCall.html#drawRanges) method.